# Image map control (ocx)

Tags: vb6, imagemap, ocx

do you know of any image map control, that can used to translate an image to clickable regions?

I'm currently looking to third-party versions, freeware or shareware.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to to this is to have various image controls covering the area of the picture to be clicked. There are better alternatives using regions or coordinate checking but I don't know any controls for it.